# How do I turn off the shutter sound for the Android camera?

Tags: camera, 2.2-froyo

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I disable the 'click' sound on the camera app?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/89/how-do-i-disable-the-click-sound-on-the-camera-app)

If the phone isn't in silent mode, taking a picture using the stock camera application always plays a "shutter" sound. Is there a way to turn the sound off?

I'm using stock Android 2.2 on a Nexus One.

Comment: Surreptitious photography? Nothing bad could *ever* come of that...

Comment: I remember reading at one point how some places have laws (or proposed laws) that are designed to ensure that all personal devices that can capture imagery (still or audio) have to be apparent when they are capturing...

Comment: I remember reading about that, too, but putting the phone into silent mode also silences the camera shutter noise, so I don't think such a law is the issue.

Comment: The ultimate responsibility to ensure that the device you're using (and the manner in which you're using it) compiles with the law is *yours*, not the OS developer's.

Answer (score 2):

I'm on android 2.1 and am on a Samsung so this may not be exactly the same for you. To disable the shutter sound I launch the camera then (with the camera in landscape mode):

1. Tap the triangle on the left of the camera frame to show the options round the camera.
2. Tap the Settings icon (cog) on the bottom right.
3. Tap the spanner tab on the top.
4. Tap the down arrow on the right to page down.
5. Tap the button next to **Shutter Sound**.
6. Select **Off**.

Comment: This option does not appear to be available using stock android 2.1 or 2.2.

Comment: Shame, I'll leave this answer up though as it works on some phones

Answer (score 2):

I located the audio file for the camera shutter: **/system/media/audio/ui/camera_click.ogg**. Removing or renaming the file (requires root access?) should stop the sound from being played.

Answer (score 0):

If the stock camera doesn't provide you the option how about simply downloading another camera software that allows you to remove the shutter sound.
(I'm on HTC Hero with sense and it has the option)

Answer (score -1):

The camera preference or system preference should have this setting, may be you can try to find?

Answer (score -1):

- Download the [Ring Toggle](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.swwomm.ringtoggle&feature=search_result) App. This is a useful app to have anyway. It lets you switch between these modes: "Ring & Vibrate", "Ring Only", "Vibrate Only", "Silent"
- Set up the "Ring Toggle" Widget on your home screen
- Click on the "Ring Toggle" Widget and set it to either "**Vibrate Only**" or "**Silent**"

Now when you use the Camera app, the shutter will be silent.

Note that Ring Toggle affects everything else as well (i.e. incoming call, email, SMS, etc)

Comment: Thanks for the response, but this question is about how to silence just the camera shutter noise, not the entire phone.

Comment: @CodeSavvyGeek: If the UI doesn't present this option, this may be your only choice.