# How can I turn off the shutter sound for the camera on droid x running 2.2 froyo?

Tags: 2.2-froyo, motorola-droid-x

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I disable the 'click' sound on the camera app?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/89/how-do-i-disable-the-click-sound-on-the-camera-app)

I'd appreciate any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should check [this question](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/89/how-do-i-disable-the-click-sound-on-the-camera-app) for a solution.