# how to turn off camera sound besides lowering the volume on i9220?

Tags: settings, audio, camera

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I disable the ‘click’ sound on the camera app?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/89/how-do-i-disable-the-click-sound-on-the-camera-app)
>   [How do I turn off the shutter sound for the Android camera?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/710/how-do-i-turn-off-the-shutter-sound-for-the-android-camera)

We have a Samsung i9220.

How to turn off camera sound besides lowering the volume?

Rooting is not an option.

Comment: Also: http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/2203/how-can-i-turn-off-the-shutter-sound-for-the-camera-on-droid-x-running-2-2-froyo?rq=1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Besides lowering volume there is no option available with out rooting.
or else you can find [3rd Party Camera Apps](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=slide.cameraZoom.composites&feature=more_from_developer) with this feature.