# How do I switch the shutter sound on the Samsung Galaxy?

Tags: samsung, camera

I have gone into my camera settings and selected the shutter sound I want but still, no sound when I use the camera.

Is this a fault, or am I missing something?

Comment: Is your phone on silent/vibrate mode?

Comment: You seem to have the opposite problem of this question: http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/89/how-do-i-disable-the-click-sound-on-the-camera-app . Answers there may be helpful, however.

Comment: There are tons of Samsung devices called Galaxy, please add your model.

Answer (score 4):

Go into Settings and there's an option for "Shutter Sound".  You can choose between three different sounds and off.

*I'm assuming you mean the Galaxy S and not the Galaxy Tab.*

[image: screenshot] [image: screenshot]
<sup>click images for larger variants</sup>

*via [DroidBar.net](http://droidbar.net/2010/12/how-to-turn-off-camera-shutter-sound-on-samsung-galaxy-s-gt-i9000/)*

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem - but discovered that I had system volume turned right down in Settings/Sound/Volume :)

Comment: Make sure your phone's volume is turned up.