# How do I get the camera of the Lenovo ThinkPad to stop making a sound when I take a picture?

Tags: camera, lenovo-thinkpad-tablet

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I disable the 'click' sound on the camera app?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/89/how-do-i-disable-the-click-sound-on-the-camera-app)

I'm not sure if this question is specific to Lenovo ThinkPads or if it is more general to Android 3.1 devices (I haven't upgraded to ICS yet since I don't want to risk losing root right now).

But basically, even when I turn the volume all the way down to 0, my ThinkPad still always makes a sound whenever I take a picture with it.

Answer (score 2):

You're root, you could replace the sound files with silent clips. This is what I've found:

```
find /system -name '*ogg' | grep cam
/system/media/audio/ui/camera_click.ogg
/system/media/audio/ui/camera_focus.ogg
```

[Audacity](http://audacity.sourceforge.net) is a free and open editor to create an empty or  silent sample and export it as an ogg file.

EDIT: According to [this](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/89/how-do-i-disable-the-click-sound-on-the-camera-app?rq=1) question/answer you can also delete or rename the camera_click.ogg file. Plus: Before you do, you need to

```
mount -oremount,rw /system
[remove/edit the above ogg files]
mount -oremount,ro /system
```

Comment: According to [this question's](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/89/how-do-i-disable-the-click-sound-on-the-camera-app?rq=1) answers renaming/deleting the file works too, no nned for a silent clip.

Comment: Thanks for the hint, added that to the answer (sorry for the former typos, I really shouldn't answer on the go on my phone :-)

Answer (score 0):

For non-root users (who cannot remount `/system` read/write), there are also some helpful apps in the playstore -- e.g. [Silent Camera](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=soft.kinoko.SilentCamera) from Kinoko, or [Silent Camera](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=jp.marufu.android.toycamera) from Reason Rare Rat, or Debys [SilentCam](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.toide.silentcam). And more...