# Disable system "tick" sound

Tags: audio, volume-control, silent-mode, t-mobile-sidekick-4g

I have a Sidekick 4g. This device has a system wide "tick" like sound that plays every time I do various things (click links, click items in list of RSS app, click threads in messaging app etc...) I would really prefer it if my device did not make this sound but the only way I've found to get it to stop is turn the volume all the way down, but then I can no longer hear my ringers.

Does anyone know of a way to eliminate this sound without the need to put my device in silent mode?

Comment: On a Galaxy S2 running ICS 4.0.3, such options are available in the SOUND category in the main Android options. uncheck TOUCH SOUNDS

Answer (score 3):

While typing this question this was one of the links that the site provided me with:

[How do I disable the 'click' sound on the camera app?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/89/how-do-i-disable-the-click-sound-on-the-camera-app)

Turns out a similar method can be used to disable the system "tick" sound in question as can the camera shutter sound.

I deleted(moved) this file:

```
/system/media/audio/ui/TW_Touch.ogg
```

and then rebooted my device, now I am free to navigate my phone in peace and quiet! and I won't miss txt's or calls because of my device being in silent.

**EDIT:** upon doing a better job of looking in the settings I found that this option is actually present in `Settings->Sound->Audible selection` Disabling it there is the preferred solution since it requires no root. (don't know how I managed to miss this the 2 times I've looked)

Comment: Thank you for answering back. Just curious, wasn't there any option in settings?

Comment: @roxan Now I feel silly. I've definitely looked in the settings before and come up empty, but just now I checked again, and indeed it is there. Is labled `Audible selection` on my device. And it does do away with this sound.

Comment: Haha! happens. I think you should also update your answer to reflect this fact so some other people also doesn't have to go though the trouble you did.