# How can I make the system folder writable without rooting?

Tags: file-system, system

My device is `Sprint Samsung Galaxy S III`

Model number: `SPH-L710`

I want to do this, because I want to stop the camera shutter sound.
And I don't want to root my device.

Comment: If you could do this then the entire security framework of Android would basically be broken, since you could modify system files anytime you wanted. You'll have to modify your device (temp or permanent root or a custom ROM/boot image with root) to access `/system`.

Comment: @eldarerathis Excuse me, I didn't understand that! Could you please explain more for me?

Comment: Well, the system protects a lot of personal/valuable information by restricting access to certain features and files. For example, your text messages, call logs, emails and the like are all stored on disk somewhere. If you could write to `/system` without restriction then you could modify or replace the portions of the OS that enforce these rules, bypass all of these restrictions, and access all of the data on the phone; this would mean that apps on your phone could do the same thing, and potentially steal your personal info or use your phone in unsavory ways without your knowledge.

Comment: There are probably other issues aside from security, though. You could accidentally brick your phone, for example (or a malicious app could brick it on purpose).

Comment: Also note that it is illegal in some places to mute the camera shutter sound.

Comment: @MatthewRead Any idea which countries?

Comment: @LiamW We do have [a closed question](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/32442/1465) about it, but I don't know much more specifically.

Comment: Why don't you simply ask "How can I disable/turn off/stop the camera shutter sound on may Galaxy S III?" and wait till the answers come in? [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/156683)

Comment: Ultimately, this is a duplicate of http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/89/how-do-i-disable-the-click-sound-on-the-camera-app

Comment: I don't know why this  question was downvoted, even though it has multiple problems.

Answer (score 5):

There is absolutely no way to do this without root, and for a good reason.

If an app was do do this imagine the havok that would ensue?

You will have to root your device, either temporarily or permanently, to do this.

Comment: Which mean I can't turn off the camera shutter sound???!!

Comment: @user1843769 Without rooting, correct - although *some* devices have the ability to do it without modifying system values.

Answer (score 1):

You could physically remove or block the speaker. That would prevent the camera from making a noise (no, plugging in headphones won't prevent the external speaker from making a shutter sound).

Aside from that, you really do have to root your device. Or at least put a custom rom on your device (which usually requires root or an unlocked bootloader, not to mention that almost every custom rom has root enabled by default).

Answer (score 0):

Yes You can change system.files without root through ADB by booting TWRP or CWM temporarily and by mounting system in options .

Answer (score -1):

You could create an updater-script to access the system and mute the shutter sound, without rooting your phone. http://www.freeyourandroid.com/guide/introdution_to_edify

http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1610121

You should include an update-binary and an empty line at the end of the updater-script.

Comment: If they aren't rooted, how do they flash? They won't have a custom recovery.