# How can I mute the camera shutter on Motorola RAZR i (ICS, without rooting)

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, audio, camera, motorola-razr-i

Even when I silence the device the camera shutter continues to making sound.

I know that using rooting alternative we can move or delete the correspondent ogg file*. But i'm looking for a less invasive/complex alternative.

(*) [How do I disable the 'click' sound on the camera app?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/89/how-do-i-disable-the-click-sound-on-the-camera-app)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While I 100% agree with [Liam's answer](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/35970/16575), there are still solutions for countries where that law doesn't apply (and to tell you a big secret: those solutions even work when the law is in effect -- but then you run the risk of punishment yourselves if you use such a solution where you shouldn't).

[Searching the playstore for "shutter sound off"](https://play.google.com/store/search?q=shutter+sound+off&c=apps) yields more than 100 results. As usual, not all of them are really hits: Most of the "spy cams" surely will disable the sound, but most likely you want to use your own camera app, and not one of those.

If you are rooted, you can simply delete the sound file for the camera shutter sound. Aside from this, an [article on AndroidAdvices](http://androidadvices.com/turn-camera-shutter-sound-android-phones/) offers 3 different solutions:

1. Put your phone in Silent Mode

   > By keeping the incoming calls ring volume to zero you can keep your phone in silent and thereby there will be no sound when you take a snap or record a video. This is the easiest way by which you can turn off the shutter sound. But mind you that you will not be notified of any incoming calls or any SMS or email that you receive. i.e., to stop shutter sound you need to put your phone in silent mode.
2. Use [Uva Silent Widget Camera Android App](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=Cam.SILENT) (well, or one of the others from above search results)
3. Install CyanogenMod

   > Once the CyanogenMod 7.1.0 up and installed on your rooted phone, you need to go through the *Settings > CyanogenMod settings > Sound* and then select *Mute camera shutter*.

On some devices with ICS, the camera app itself offers a feature to disable the shutter sound:

[image: CameraShutter in Menu]

Comment: Thanks for the answer @Izzy. Unfortunately, these solutions doesn't work in this problem's context (Motorola Razr i ICS 4.0.4). **Putting the phone in silent mode** doesn't mute the cam in this context. **The Uva Silent Widget Camera Android App** has a note about Android 4.0 and doesn't work either: _"Android 4.0 (Galaxy Nexus) is currently not supported. Please be patient while we continue to work on this."_ I'm pretty sure that **CyanogenMod** solves this problem, but it is further "agressive" (comparing with rooting).

Comment: If something like that Uva Widget would be a solution for you, just follow the Playstore Search link. Plenty of similar solutions there. You could e.g. try [Camera ICS](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.moblynx.cameraics), which explicitly lists *Silent mode (no shutter sound, might not work on some devices)* in its features. Take your pick ;)

Comment: Camera ICS has the option to mute the camera shutter and ... IT WORKS! Thanks for the tip @Izzy.

Comment: Glad it worked out! Enjoy :)

Answer (score 2):

Sorry to tell you this, but due to laws in many countries, there is no way to disable it without removing the file which needs root.

Sorry to be the bearer of bad news!

Comment: In countries where this law dosen't exists, a shutter sound may be very inappropriate and even baffling in certains situations. In these countries, with the law about shutter sound, people are habituated and know hot to handle this kind of situation.

Answer (score -1):

Just disable or mute your media sound; that will also mute the camera shutter sound on ICS.