# How to turn off the camera shutter sound on LG G2 mini?

Tags: settings, root-access, camera, file-system, camera-sound

Where is located the **camera shutter sound file** on *LG G2 mini* (Android 4.4.2)? Or how else to **turn** that annoying sound **off**?

***None*** of the solutions recommended in similar questions here does work. The phone looks like requiring its own solution.

The accepted answer for [How do I disable the 'click' sound on the camera app?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/89/68373) recommends deleting `/system/media/audio/ui/camera_click.ogg`. I deleted the file, rebooted the phone several times, however the camera did not stop making the shutter noise. N.B.: My phone *is* rooted.

I want either to delete the file or replace it with an no-sound file, however the location given in the related question does not seem to work on LG G2 mini.

The solution with setting `ro.camera.sound.forced=0` in `build.prop` does **not** work either.

Explanation to avoid some off-topic answers:

1. LG G2 mini native camera application has 4 predefined shutter sounds, with no "None" option.
   [image]
2. I don't consider switching the phone on *silent* as a solution.
3. I am not asking *why* LG does not have the option (whether it is somewhere legal or not), but *how* to turn the sound off.
4. My phone is rooted so I can change system files. I just haven't found *which* files should be changed and *how*.
5. The problem might be deeper. As the description of the [Camera Sounds Off!](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=de.akirilow.tool.cso&hl=en) application says:

> Don't work on some devices by ...
>
> *LG (The LG's camera app has own not removable sound files!)

Actually, I don't believe in anything *really* "not removable" :), but removing them probably will require some trick which I have not found.

Comment: You sure you don't have it in Camera Settings or Settings? I guess LG phones do have this setting.

Comment: I am sure I do have it in Camera Settings :) However, there are 4 predefined sounds, I can only chose one of those. I want to have *no* shutter sound. I cannot find where those sounds are stored in the file system.

Comment: Okay :) I thought "None" would be an option.

Comment: I'm not sure about the LG G2 Mini, but on the LG G2, I'm able to mute shutter and focus sounds by putting my phone on silent.

Comment: @Noah: Putting the phone on silent is not a solution. It's a workaround (and not a good one :) ).

Comment: In some places it's illegal to take photos with the shutter sound off, that's probably why they didn't give you the option.

Comment: @user3949142 Correct, it was introduced because creeps took upskirt photos of women, mainly on escalators and stairs.

Answer (score 2):

You need to be rooted to do this!

1. Download and open any root browser. (I am Using Root Explorer for these instructions, ES File Manager works also)
2. Go to System
3. Go from Read Only to Read/Write
4. Find Biuld Prop
5. Open with text editor
6. Find ro.camera.sound.forced
7. Change the 1 to 0
8. Save Changes
9. Reboot

SOURCE: http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2051384

Comment: 1. There was not such an item in the file.
2. I added a new line `ro.camera.sound.forced=0`.
3. I rebooted. It does not help :(

Answer (score -1):

You were on the right track. You only have the wrong file it is shutter.ogg that makes the sound !!!

Comment: There is no such a file. Either I've already deleted it or it has never been there.